# Fast algorithm to check if a query line segment contains a point that is not covered by $n$ disks in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: computational-geometry

I have a list of $n$ disks in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with center and radius $(x_i, y_i, r_i)$. I also have $Q$ line segments $l_1, l_2, ..., l_Q$. I am interested in preprocessing the $n$ disks (or the line segments!), to answer the following query:

Given segment $l_k$, is there a point on $l_k$ not inside any disk?

There is an obvious $O(nQ)$ time solution that is just brute-force, but I am wondering if pre-processing the disks (or the lines) somehow can speed things up.

I would prefer hints over full answers. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with computational geometry, but out of curiosity, how does your obvious $O(nQ)$ brute-force solution work? *My* obvious brute-force solution requires time $O(Qn\log n)$; perhaps it could be improved to $O(Qn\alpha(n))$ using a union-find data structure.

Comment: Why do you consider a set of line segments as part of input data? You already selected one of them, so what's the point to think about others? May be, to consider a set of $n$ disks and a *single* segment only?